# How does the method Matrix.setLookAtM work in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

How does `Matrix.setLookAtM` work?  I've been searching all over, and can't find an explanation. I understand that the first three coordinates are to define the location of the camera in the world space, and I take it that "center of view" means the `x, y, z` coordinate I'm looking at in the world space. That being the case, what does the "up vector" mean/do?

If there is a previous question or tutorial that I've overlooked, I would be happy to accept that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Up vector is what the camera considers "up", i.e.: If you were looking forward and held your hand up, that is your "up" vector. Just set it to `0, 1, 0`.  I'm not an Android developer, but I'm guessing it's similar to `gluLookAt()`.

What the function is really doing is setting up a view matrix for you. It needs the eye position to establish where the camera will be. After that, it will subtract eye position from center and normalize it to get a forward vector. Then it will cross the forward vector with the up vector to get a right vector. After normalizing all three, it can construct a matrix from those `x, y, z` vectors giving you a basic model view matrix.

It just discretizes the math for you.

Comment: Ah I see, it didn't cross my mind, but I suppose the camera could be upside down or sideways or what have you, and the up vector determines that.  Makes perfect sense, thanks so much for explaining that.  :)

Comment: setLookAtM takes 9 parameters (excluding an offset value and a reference to your output matrix), i.e. eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ - Hw do these relate to your recommended setting of `0,1,0`?

Comment: @JCutting8 The last 3 parameters.